# How to use QueryBuilder with 2 tables

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I'm trying to use the `QueryBuilder` in `Symfony` and `Doctrine` and do a query with 2 tables. This will be the code in SQL:

```
SELECT a.id, a.url FROM example1 AS a, example2 AS b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

I think it's a simple question but i didn't find anything on Internet...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377079/doctrine-query-builder-using-inner-join-with-conditions Regards

Answer (score 0):

Selection from multiple tables is some kind of alias for JOIN syntax

```
SELECT a.id, a.url FROM example1 AS a INNER JOIN example2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

So I think with JOIN syntax you can do it with Doctrine easier ;)