# Join in Doctrine Query Language

Tags: sql-server, symfony, dql

I'm having trouble converting sql to dql. This what I trying to achieve when the users are in activity table they should not be able to edit an inactive state but state is located in another table.

SQL

```
SELECT Activity1.Payrollperiodid, PayrollPeriod.state
FROM Activity1
INNER JOIN PayrollPeriod ON Activity1.payrollperiodid = Payrollperiod.payrollperiodid
where PayrollPeriod.state=1;
```

DQL

```
 public function findBytransid($payrollperiodid)
{
  $repository=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity');
  $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
  $qb->select('a');
  $qb->innerJoin('a.payrollperiodid', 'p');
  $qb->where('a.payrollperiodid=:payrollperiodid and a.status=:1');
  $qb->setParameter('payrollperiodid', $payrollperiodid);
  $qb->setParameter('status', 1);
  return $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Change `:1` to `:status`

Answer (score 0):

[Same problem with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377079/doctrine-query-builder-using-inner-join-with-conditions)

Maybe this solve your problem

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();    
$qb =  $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity')
        ->createQueryBuilder('a');

return $qb
    ->select('a')
    ->innerJoin('a.payrollperiodid', 'p',Join::WITH,  $qb->expr()->eq('a.payrollperiodid',':id'))
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('a.status',':status'))
    ->setParameters([
        'id'=>$payrollperiodid,
        'status' =>1
    ])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: I get this error: Attempted to load class "Join" from namespace

Comment: replace Join::WITH to 'WITH'

Comment: [Read about Joins in documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$repository=$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Activity');
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb->select('a','pp');
        $qb->Join('a.payrollperiodid','pp');
        $qb->where('pp.state = :state');
        $qb->setParameter('state', 0);

        return $results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```