# How to select a specific connection between tables in doctrine querybuilder with symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

I am using symfony 5.4 with doctrine-bundle 2.4.
I've got an entity "sending" where I connect addresses with different connections

```
class Sending
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="getSendingAsSender")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sending_sender_address")
     */
    private $sender;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Address::class, inversedBy="getSendingAsRecipient")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sending_recipient_address")
     */
    private $recipient;
}
```

and the corresponding address entity.

When creating an object of type sending I can access sender and recipient, so the definitions of the objects seem to be fine.

Now I want to create a list of all senders OR recipients by using querybuilder

```
$builder = $this->entitiyManager->getRepository(Sending::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->join(Address::class, 'a')
...
```

This creates a

```
select ... from sending s inner join address a
```

without any connection data or on clauses and without the m:n join table in between.
When adding a ->join('sending_sender_address','sa') before the address join it tells me, that there is not entity sending_sender_address.

What I finally need is a collection of address objects which are senders (or recipients) of any or selected sendings.

How do I do that connection properly and how can I choose which of the connection tables should be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine query builder using inner join with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377079/doctrine-query-builder-using-inner-join-with-conditions)

Comment: Should have worked, thanks. Just Dylan's answer below was much closer to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do something like:

```
    $builder = $this->entitiyManager->getRepository(Sending::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('s');

    //check however you want which data you need
    if($type === ''){
        $builder->join('sa.sender', 'a');
    }else{
        $builder->join('sa.recipient', 'a');
    }
```

Or if **$type** is `sender` or `recipient`:

```
    $builder = $this->entitiyManager->getRepository(Sending::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->join('s.'.$type, 'a')
    ;
```

You don't need to add a where clause to only get addresses related from your Sending entity, just select addresses from your join.

Comment: Yeah, that was the perfect hint (almost). I just had to swap Addresses to be the main part and join the sendings. Otherwise selecting addresses was empty. Now it works as wanted. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can still do it by having sending as the main part, but if you specifically want to select addresses you need to use `->addSelect('sa.sender')` or `->select('sa.sender')`, feel free to validate my answer if it helped you